# Powerpivot / Powerchart - Need values, not sum

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I've got 2 Excel sheets with some data.
Excel 1:

```
Url   | Milliseconds
url/1 | 0.6534
url/2 | 0.5422
url/3 | 4.2133
```

Excel 2:

```
Url   | Milliseconds
url/1 | 0.8531
url/2 | 0.3254
url/3 | 3.5124
```

I want to aggregate this date in 1 chart, so I figured I could go using the PowerChart offered by the PowerPivot functionality.

Using PowerPivot I've added the 2 Excel files as a datasource and managed to create a chart.
I've also created a relationship between the `Excel 1.Url` field and the `Excel 2.Url` field.

Now when creating the chart, the `Excel 1.Milliseconds` field shows up correct. When I add the `Excel 2.Milliseconds` column to the chart (in the Values block), it shows the Sum of Milliseconds.
This is possibly due to the fact the field value is set to be the Sum. But I can't change this to be the actual value of the field.
Below is a screenshot of what I'm dealing with (dutch Excel 2013)

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wm4bwraz8b1uqxp/SOExcelPowerPivot.png]

Am I missing something? That's quite possible as this is the first time I'm working with PowerPivot.

Comment: Jan, what is the relationship between those tables? Is there any difference in *Milliseconds* between Excel 1 and Excel 2?

Comment: I've set the relationship to the 'URL' field of the sheets. Both sheets have the same URL's in them. The only thing which differs are the Miliseconds. I want to show the differences between the miliseconds in a chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Jan**, the solution should be quite simple:

- Create a *separate table of URLs* (I named it **URL_list**) and link your source tables (**URL_1** and **URL_2** in my diagram) to this table. You should get something like this:

[image]

- Create new *calculated fields* (Excel 2013, in 2010 it's called *Measure*) for calculating the average load time:

Formula for table **URL_1** (I called it **Avg Time in MS_1**, see my diagram):

```
=AVERAGE(URL_1[Millisecond])
```

Formula for table **URL_2** (**Avg Time in MS_2**):

```
=AVERAGE(URL_2[Millisecond])
```

- Once this is done, simply insert a new **PowerPivot table** and add **PivotChart** using *Options* ribbon. Drag URL from table *URL_list* onto *Rows* and then add the newly created calculated fields.

**The result should look like this:**

[image]

I have uploaded the [Excel file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/258211/StackOverflow-URLs.xlsx) to my Desktop public folder. Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks exactly the way I need, thanks! Will try it out tomorrow or maybe later, depending on the tasks I need to tend to.

Comment: Great Jan, hope it works out. If you find it useful, please could you accept my answer then?

Comment: This actually worked! At first it didn't, but seeing your example I discovered the relations where the wrong way. I had set them from `URL_list` to `URL_1` and `URL_list` to `URL_2`. It needs to be the other way around, so `URL_1` to `URL_list` and `URL_2` to `URL_list`.